# C# using switch statement with multiple key inputs

Tags: c#, switch-statement, user-input

I'm trying to make a little device for a board game I play. I know virtually nothing about programming and I thought this would be a great way to get started. I have six buttons to utilize on my QT Py. The needed functions are as follows:

[+1]

[+10]

[+100]

[-1]

[-10]

[-100]

[toggle attack/defense]

[next page (for tracking multiple characters)]

So far this is all I have:

```
using System;

namespace Counter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var atk = 0;
            var def = 0;
            bool quit = false;

            while (quit == false)
            {
                switch (Console.ReadKey().Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.D1:
                        atk++;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.D2:
                        atk--;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.D3:
                        def++;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.D4:
                        def--;
                        break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make the software recognize multiple inputs, e.g. [D5+D1 = pwr+10]? I'm going to need to multi-bind inputs like mad in order to have all the functionality I want.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I believe the Console namespace doesn't have anything in it that can tell whether the input was a key down (press) or a key up (release), what you wanna do is use native functions that can asynchronously tell which keys are currently pressed and whether it's a key down or key up, there's an example here: https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/

Here's a summary:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
       
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine($"{(Keys)vkCode} is key down? {(IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN == wParam}");
        
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public static void Main(){
        var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

        // Hide
        ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks! I've since determined I need to spend more time learning to code, since this is all Greek. My project is shelved for now while I learn.